# FluentD, grep only specific logs events

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, efk

I have logs, and I want to grep only the logs and send to Elasticsearch which contains 'error="400 - Rejected by Elasticsearch' and 'failed to parse field' and ignore the others.

```
log:2022-02-04 23:56:43 +0530 [warn]: #0 dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchErrorHandler::ElasticsearchError error="400 - Rejected by Elasticsearch [error type]: invalid_index_name_exception [reason]: 'Invalid index name [-2022.02.04], must not start with '_', '-', or '+''" location=nil
```

and

```
2022-02-03 01:42:40 +0530 [warn]: #0 dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchErrorHandler::ElasticsearchError error="400 - Rejected by Elasticsearch [error type]: mapper_parsing_exception [reason]: 'failed to parse field [log] of type [text] in document with id 'BnYRvH4BMXwCDVGBTa8Z'. Preview of field's value: '''" location=nil
```

MY Config>>

```
fluentd.conf: |-    
      <filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.fluentd**>
        @type grep
        <regexp>
            key log
            pattern /(^Rejected|^error="400|^mapper_parsing_exception)/
        </regexp>
      </filter>
      <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.fluentd**>
        @type elasticsearch
        @log_level info
        suppress_type_name true
        host "eslogging.abc.com"
        port 80
        reload_connections false
        logstash_format true
        logstash_prefix "fluentd"
        reconnect_on_error true
        request_timeout 2147483648
        retry_max_times 3
        num_threads 4
        compression_level best_compression
        compression gzip
        include_timestamp true
        utc_index false
        time_key_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%z"
        time_key time
        reload_on_failure true
        <buffer>
           @type file
           path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/cluster-logging-fluentd.buffer
           flush_mode interval
           retry_type exponential_backoff
           flush_thread_count 4
           flush_interval 3s
           retry_forever true 
           retry_max_interval 30
           chunk_limit_size 8MB
           queue_limit_length 20
           overflow_action block
        </buffer>
      </match>
```

Comment: Please add your config that you've tried so far and couldn't get to work.

Comment: @Azeem. Added, please check

Comment: Both error messages contain `error="400`. I believe you can simply write `pattern /error="400/` and test it.

Comment: If you want to enforce the exact sequence along with those two specific exceptions, you can use something like this `/(error="400.*Rejected by Elasticsearch).*(invalid_index_name_exception|mapper_parsing_exception)/`.

Comment: @Azeem Not working, match pattern added into log filed and my logs are coming in log 
{
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_source": {
    "log": "      pattern /(error=\"400.*Rejected by Elasticsearch).*(invalid_index_name_exception|mapper_parsing_exception)/\n",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "@timestamp": "2022-02-07T12:28:59.314514163+00:00"
  },
  "fields": {
    "log": [
      "      pattern /(error=\"400.*Rejected by Elasticsearch).*(invalid_index_name_exception|mapper_parsing_exception)/\n"
    ],
    "time": [
      "2022-02-07T12:28:59.314Z"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Please add a sample log in the question.

Comment: @Azeem I already added
adding again
```
2022-02-03 01:42:40 +0530 [warn]: #0 dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchErrorHandler::ElasticsearchError error="400 - Rejected by Elasticsearch [error type]: mapper_parsing_exception [reason]: 'failed to parse field [log] of type [text] in document with id 'BnYRvH4BMXwCDVGBTa8Z'. Preview of field's value: '''" location=nil
```

Comment: Right. Got confused between the ES log with the original error log. Anyways, what about `pattern /error="400/`? Did you try it?

Comment: @Azeem I tried, it won't work